# If $\langle v, Av \rangle = 1$ for all $\|v\| = 1$, then $A = I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Theorem: If $\langle v, Av \rangle = 1$ for all $\|v\| = 1$, then $A = I$, where $A$ is a bounded operator from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$.

From what I can tell, converting to the form of $v^\dagger A^\dagger v$, can obtain that the diagonal elements of the matrix form of $A$ must all be one, by subbing in each basis element for $v$ in the equation, but I cannot prove the rest (that the rest of the matrix is zeroes). Maybe another method is correct. I think maybe something to do with eigendecomposition might be the right direction (show A must decompose into eigenvalues all 1 with identity basis).

Comment: Question: What happens to this question if we replace $\mathbb{C}^n$ by $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: presumably the same result, $A = I$

Comment: At least Kenny Lau's proof won't work as there are skew operators (rotate by 90 degrees in the plane).

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean. I think showing $B$ is skew symmetric still works, but yeah I think it sufficient to see that $B$ is self adjoint instead (rather trivially), to allow invokng the spectral theorem to show B is the 0 matrix.

Comment: Ah, my bad. It's definitely not 'trivially self adjoint' (meaning $B$ is symmetric) or whatever I said. Yeah, it doesn't hold. My bad!

Comment: That was fun, identity plus the rotator is the counterexample for $\mathbb{R}^2$ (see below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another approach.

---

Lemma: if a matrix $B$ satisfies $\langle v, Bv \rangle = 0$ for all $v$, then $B = 0$.

Proof: For any $x$ and $y$, we have:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\langle x+y, B(x+y) \rangle &=& 0 \\
\langle x, Bx \rangle + \langle x, By \rangle + \langle y, Bx \rangle + \langle y, By \rangle &=& 0 \\
0 + \langle x, By \rangle + \langle y, Bx \rangle + 0 &=& 0 \\
\langle x, By \rangle &=& -\langle y, Bx \rangle
\end{array}$$

Therefore, $B$ is skew-symmetric, i.e. $B = -B^*$.

Then, we have $BB^* = B^*B$, since $BB^* = -B^*B^* = B^*B$.

From the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Normal_matrices), $B$ is diagonalizable, i.e. it has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. However, the eigenvalues must all be $0$.

Therefore, the eigenspace of $0$ of $B$ is the full space, so $B$ is $0$.

---

Consider $B = A-I$. Then, for every $v$, $\langle v,Bv \rangle = \langle v,Av \rangle - \langle v,v \rangle = 0$.

Therefore, from the lemma above, $B=0$, i.e. $A=I$.

Comment: Both are fantastic answers. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user517348 welcome

Comment: @Kenny - what happens if we work in $\mathbb{R}^n$? The proof won't work - is there a counterexample?

Comment: @max_zorn The spectral theorem only applies in $\Bbb C^n$. Rotation matrix is a counter-example to my lemma.

Comment: @Kenny: A yes, so A = Id + rotation is a counterexample to the original statement! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\la}{\langle}\newcommand{\ra}{\rangle}
\newcommand{\id}{\operatorname{id}}$

\begin{align*}
& \langle v, Av\rangle=\la v,\id v\ra \forall \| v\|=1\\
\Longrightarrow &  \langle v, Av\rangle=\la v,\id v\ra \forall v \\
\Longrightarrow & \langle u, Av\rangle=\la u,\id v\ra \forall u,v (\mbox{ by polarization } \la u,Av\ra =\sum_{k=0}^3 i^k \la u+i^k v, A(u+i^k v)\ra )\\
\Longrightarrow & A=\id .
\end{align*}

Comment: Much more elegant than both of my proofs! I wonder if the last step works for endomorphisms of infinite-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @KennyLau It works for bounded operators of any complex Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Do you have a counter-example for unbounded operators?

Comment: The last step is because $\langle u, (A-\operatorname{id})v\rangle=0\forall u,v \Longrightarrow  \langle(A-\operatorname{id})v,(A-\operatorname{id})v\rangle=0\Longrightarrow (A-\operatorname{id})v=0\Longrightarrow A=\operatorname{id} $. The proof also works for unbounded operators of Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. So this theorem holds for every complex inner-product space.

Comment: You are right. Inner product space is enough.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I cannot find a reference for polarization identity of this form (it looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity#Homogeneous_polynomials_of_higher_degree, but subbing in $Av$ for $v$ does not give seem to give same result as your solution), and I'm not too sure exactly how it implies $\langle u, Av \rangle = \langle u, \id v \rangle$ for all $u$ and $v$. I tried to work through the algebra and got stuck.

Comment: You can check the polarization identity straightforward without any reference. For your second question,$\newcommand{\la}{\langle}\newcommand{\ra}{\rangle}
\newcommand{\id}{\operatorname{id}}$ $\la u, A v\ra=\sum_{k=0}^3 i^k \la u+i^k v, A(u+i^k v)\ra )=\sum_{k=0}^3 i^k \la u+i^k v, \id(u+i^k v)\ra )=\la u,\id v\ra$.

Comment: Ah, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is equivalent to $\langle v, Av \rangle = \|v\|^2$ for all $v$.

---

I now prove that there are $n$ mutually orthogonal eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$:

By the fundamental theorem of algebra, there is an eigenpair $(\lambda,v)$ of $A$. Then, $\overline \lambda \|v\|^2 = \|v\|^2$ by the condition and by properties of complex inner product, whence $\lambda = 1$.

Now, prove that the orthogonal complement of $v$ also satisfies the condition, and proceed by induction (since the orthogonal complement has one dimension lower than the original vector space).

---

Then, the eigenspace is the whole space, and the eigenvalue is $1$, so the matrix must be the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

A way to see this at a glance:

> If $X$ is a Hilbert space and  $A : X \to X$ is a bounded operator such that $\langle Ax,x\rangle \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $x \in X$ then $A$ is self-adjoint.

$\langle Av, v\rangle = \|v\|^2 \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ so $A$ is self-adjoint. In particular $A$ is diagonalizable.

The condition $\langle Av, v\rangle = \|v\|^2$ also gives that all eigenvalues of $A$ are equal to $1$:

$$\lambda \|v\|^2 = \langle \lambda v, v\rangle = \langle Av, v\rangle = \|v\|^2 \implies \lambda = 1$$

Hence $A$ diagonalizes to the identity matrix, so $A = I$.

Comment: Another nice and simple solution.Thanks.